# vue js firebase data refresh on document add

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

As the title suggests I'm just wondering what would a good/best practice be for refreshing the data on the client side after adding a new document to the firestore. So basically to summerize the functionality, let's say I have a form and below the form are all the documents. What would be a good way to refresh the data so I don't stress out firebase. Adding new documents is a good chunk of the app I'm working on, so it'll probably be used a lot. I'm wondering should I just add it client side if the doc was added successfully or should I just send a call for all the docs again or something else. I'm familiar with the snapshot option,  I'm just not sure if it's a good practice. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal solution would be to use snapshots. Let's look at an abstract from their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).

> **Local writes** in your app will invoke **snapshot listeners immediately**. This is because of an important feature called `latency compensation`. **When you perform a write, your listeners will be
> notified with the new data before the data is sent to the backend.**
>
> Retrieved documents have a `metadata.hasPendingWrites` property that
> indicates **whether the document has local changes that haven't been
> written to the backend yet.** You can use this property to determine
> the source of events received by your snapshot listener.

So you see, you adding the documents to the client side directly is the same as using a `firestore snapshot` because in case of local writes, the data is directly received by the listeners and will not go to the server first and then receive the data.

Also, you could even write a query to `limit` & `sort` the data and the snapshot listener will automatically handle the logic for limiting and sorting the data. Nevertheless, you can even query the data once the document is added on the client side using `get()`, but that's just beating around the bushes.

`Snapshots` were designed for this purpose of `bi-directional` updates and I would highly recommend you to use them instead.

###### Reference

- [Get Realtime Updates With Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)